# Restart IIS after Stackoverflow Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Well, sometimes I don't think before I debug. And sometimes the results of this is a StackoverflowException.

When this happens, the application seems to hang. I go to IIS and stop the pool manully, but I can't start it then (message translated from german: "currently the service cannot accept commands").

Killing the process "w3p.exe" via task manager allows me to start the pool.

But the application still hangs: When I try to access the page via browser (code with stackoverflow exception already corrected) the page is loading endless/no reaction.

The only workaround I found out is to restart the whole computer. Is there another way to get the IIS pool running fine after an StackOverflowException?

Comment: Usually just stop debugging should solve your problems withour restaring any services or killing processes. Doesn't this work for you? Are you remote debugging or something?

Comment: You can always try `iisreset.exe` - that should restart the entire IIS.

Comment: You can try recycling the application pool.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But "Stop debugging", "Reset IIS" nor "recycling the app-pool" doesn't seem to work. The whole web is still not accessible.

Comment: Are there other services that your websites uses, that also need to be restarted?

Comment: @PeterB Great hint, thanks! I restarted the asp.net-stateserver service and the website is no accessible. I reproduced the scenario again and the pool is accessible immedialy after restarting the state service :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem, thanks to @PeterB:

```
net stop aspnet_state
net start aspnet_state
```

On some systems the service is called "aspstate" instead of "aspnet_state".